# Loop through array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that I've created that is made up of sections and questions. How can I loop through the sections and display the nested questions of each section.

**Here is how I'm creating the array**

```
$db = db_open();
$query = "SELECT * FROM assessment_selections WHERE assessment_id = '".$annual_assessment["id"]."' AND selection = '1' ORDER BY timestamp ASC";
$result = db_query($db, $query);
$result = db_fetch_all($result);
if (!is_array)
    $result = array();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $section[$row['section_id']][$row['question_id']] = $row;
}
```

**Here is the array**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array // Section 1
        (
            [1] => Array // Question 1
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 70
                    [assessment_id] => 32
                    [section_id] => 1
                    [question_id] => 1
                    [selection] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1368172762
                )

        )

    [2] => Array // Section 2
        (
            [3] => Array // Question 3
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 68
                    [assessment_id] => 32
                    [section_id] => 2
                    [question_id] => 3
                    [selection] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1368166250
                )

        )

    [3] => Array // Section 3
        (
            [4] => Array // Question 4
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 69
                    [assessment_id] => 32
                    [section_id] => 3
                    [question_id] => 4
                    [selection] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1368172690
                )

        )

    [4] => Array // Section 4
        (
            [5] => Array // Question 5
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 71
                    [assessment_id] => 32
                    [section_id] => 4
                    [question_id] => 5
                    [selection] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1368174153
                )

        )

)
```

**Expected results** (How I would like to be able to echo them out in PHP)

**Section 1**

- **Question 1**
- **Question 4**
- **Question 7**

**Section 2**

- **Question 2**
- **Question 9**

**Section 3**

- **Question 3**

Comment: And what is the current (wrong) result with the code you've tried ? Please show us this code too

Comment: Pastebin your resultant array `$result`.

Comment: At least change `if (!is_array)` to `if (!is_array($result))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this loop.

```
foreach($section as $k=>$section)
{
   echo "section $k";
   foreach($section as $i=>$question)
   {
     echo "question $i ".$question['assessment_id']; //more fields available here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `foreach` again:

```php
foreach ( $data as $n => $sect) {
    echo "Section $n<br>";
    foreach ($sect as $q => $qdata) {
        echo " -> Question $q<br>";
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($section as $key => $value) {
    echo "Section ".$key;
    foreach($value as $key => $value) {
        echo "Question ".$key;
    }
}
```