# Reading nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that has a nested array shown below, my goal is to use PHP and loop through this array pulling out both the parent and child data.

```
$NestedArray = array(
             "Name" => array(
                       "Phone"=>"Text",
                       "Email"=>"12"
              )
             "Company" => array(
                       "Phone"=>"Text",
                       "Email"=>"12"
              )
);
```

Will someone please show me how to loop through this array using php.  Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477943/loop-through-array-in-php

Comment: `The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.`  See [here](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct

```
foreach($NestedArray as $sKey=>$subarray)
{
    // You can print the subarray key here too
    foreach($subarray as $key=>$value)
    {
        print $key + ": " + $value;
    }
}
```

if you want to print for debug purposes, use [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r)

```
print_r($NestedArray);
```